# Deleting data in database with dropdown menu in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am struggling with deleting data in my database with my drop-down menu.
My drop-down menu looks like this

```
<form method="post" action="admin.php">
<h3>Delete a user</h3>
<select name="username">
$sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT username FROM users");
while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){
?>

<option value="username" name="username">
<?php echo $row['username']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete User">
</form>
```

And this is displaying the users all good like i want it, so here is the php for it

```
<?php 
include('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
$username = $_POST['username'];
mysqli_query("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' ");
echo "User was deleted!";
}
?>
```

So when i hit the submit button "Delete User", it looks like i get sent to admin.php and nothing happens.

How can i fix this?
Thanks.

Comment: Why `name="username"` in `<option value="username" name="username">` ?

Comment: _Small note:_ `<option>` tags dont have a `name` attribute. The name is taken from the `<select>` tags name attribute

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Have a look at what happened to [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/) Even
[if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: That was honestly just something i tried to see if it worked, but no it is not supposed to be there.

Comment: `<option value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>" name="username">
<?php echo $row['username']; ?></option>`. everytime you submit the `value` you pass is `username`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.`<option value="username" name="username">` Need to be `<option value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>">`

2.Connection variable is missing . Need to be:-

```
mysqli_query($connection,"DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' ");
```

Modified code need to be:-

Form code:-

```
<?php
//comment these two lines when code started working fine
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

include('connect.php');
?>
<form method="post" action="admin.php">
    <h3>Delete a user</h3>
    <select name="username">
      <?php
      $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT username FROM users");
      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql)){?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></option>
      <?php }?>
    </select>
<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete User">
</form>
```

Php code:-

```
<?php
//comment these two lines when code started working fine
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors',1);

include('connect.php');
if(isset($_POST['delete'])) {
    $username = $_POST['username'];
    if(mysqli_query($connection,"DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `username` = '$username' ")){
        echo "User was deleted!";
    }
}
?>
```

Note:- Always do some [error-reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) so that you will get error and rectify that.

Your query is vulnerable to `SQL INJECTION` so read about `prepared statements` and use them.

Answer (score 3):

1. Replace `name="username"` from `<option></option>`
2. Echo value in `value` of option.
3. Connection variable missing in **admin.php** page

***Updated Code***

```
<select name="username">
  <?php
  $sql = mysqli_query($connection, "SELECT username FROM users");
  while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()){?>
    <option value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>"><?php echo $row['username']; ?></option>
  <?php }?>
</select>
```

**admin.php**

```
$stmt = $connection->prepare("DELETE FROM `users` WHERE `username` = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('s', $username);
$stmt->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not putting the value in select option that's why nothing happens
Just replace

```
<option value="username" name="username">
<?php echo $row['username']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

with

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['username']; ?>">
<?php echo $row['username']; ?></option>
<?php } ?>
```

It will work for you.

Comment: You might like to check the syntax for an `<option>` tag

Comment: As there is no `name` attribute on an `<option>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<option value="username" name="username">
<?php echo $row['username']; ?></option>
```

To

```
<option value="<?php echo $row['username'] ?>" name="username">
<?php echo $row['username']; ?></option>
```

Comment: You might like to check the syntax for an `<option>` tag